# What does the cross on a square symbol mean?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, clarinet

[image]This symbol is on a clarinet etude sheet, but I don't have any clue what it means.

[image: close up, looks like a + attached on top of a box]

Comment: And who is the particular composer?

Comment: If it's clarinet, then the key signature would help, because all those notes (B/C/C#/F/F#)use similar keys, and it may be possible to deduce the meaning from how each note should be fingered.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I’ve updated the sheet. thanks for your prompt hint.

Comment: Thanks. The bit of the key signature which is visible suggests the piece is in E and those notes are B, C#, B and F#. I don't think it's a fingering thing, particularly since it also occurs in bar 3. There are all sorts of funny symbols I've never seen before.

Comment: What if that was written for an Oehler system clarinet?  Would that make more sense?

Comment: Please add the title and composer.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not a common and standardized musical symbol, and probably has been invented by this author and explained somewhere in the text, perhaps an introduction to the book. There are several non-standard symbols: the triangle with a dot in the center, the small notes that look like 8th notes (quavers) with hollow noteheads, the numerals like "25" or "89" in italics. If you've gotten this etude out of context, like as a photocopy or pdf, I recommend finding the original publication.

Comment: @AndyBonner I  saw those as (equally nonstandard) "hollow" grace notes.

Comment: There is no chance that this is an etude, as those are written for training purposes.  This is intended for performance, and, as AB wrote, you'll need the composer's  intro/guide to know what all those one-off symbols represent.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have a different take. While it's quite melodic, and "con grandioso espressione" (with large espresso), my guess is that these symbols convey something technical and pedagogical. For violin, Galamian and Flesch and others have their own similar systems for indicating fingers that should be held down, ways to prepare future notes, bow use, etc. For instance, I'm guessing the "hollow grace notes" have to do with fingering; the symbol in question might be about breathing (coinciding with slurs, though not duplicating them).

Comment: @AndyBonner All but one of the "hollow grace notes" occur between slurs too.

Comment: They look like a fingering or perhaps breathing suggestion by the editor. Perhaps there is a guide at the start or end of the music book?These look highly specific to the editor. They are not standard music notation.

Answer (score 7):

I am neither a German speaker nor a clarinet player, so please make sure to translate the German text yourself!

This music comes from the Carl Baermann's *Vollständige Clarinett Schule* (Complete Method for Clarinet), Book 2 (Op. 64). The photo in the question is of the 5th study, *Mein Liebster Gedanke* (My Dearest Thought).

Op. 64 gives no information as to what any of the symbols mean (which is probably where OP's confusion stemmed from) but it does mention that Op. 63 provides an explanation. The original German text of Op. 63 mentions the following:

> Bei den beiden Tönen Fis und Cis
> ist nebst dem was von F und C gesagt besonders zu bemerken:
>
> a) dass beide Töne auch durch die Aushebung, welche mit dem Daumen der rechten Hand gegriffen wird, genommen werden können, welches in vielen Fällen sehr erleichtert, namentlich in ähnlichen Stellen wie z. B.:
>
> [image: example music] etc.
>
> Bei dieser Stelle wird von dem ersten H die Aushebung genommen
> und den ganzen Takt liegen gelassen.
> Das Zeichen für die Aushebung ist [image: cross symbol] und bleibt so lange giltig bis das Zeichen [image: triangle symbol] eintritt.

...which translates as:

> In addition to what was said about F and C, the two tones F sharp and C sharp should be noted in particular:
>
> a) that both tones can also be taken by the key which is played with the thumb of the right hand, which in many cases makes it much easier, especially in similar passages such as:
>
> [image: example music] etc.
>
> At this point the key is taken from the first B and left down for the whole bar. The sign for the key is [image: cross symbol] and remains valid until the sign [image: triangle symbol] appears.

This key is not present on modern clarinets.

Op. 63 and Op. 64 are available on [IMSLP:](https://imslp.org/wiki/Vollst%C3%A4ndige_Clarinett_Schule%2C_Opp.63-64_(Baermann%2C_Carl))

Answer (score -1):

The marks are a prompt to keep the r/h fingers down when crossing the break.